# Generic Covariance and contravariance

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Consider the code snippet.

```
IList<String> obj=new List<string>();
IEnumerable<Object> obj1 = obj;
```

But if i write `ICollection<Object> obj2 = obj;` it throws me a compile time error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<object>`'.

Why is  this behavior since `List<T>` implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `ICollection<T>` and also `IList<T>` is defined as

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    T this[int index] { get; set; }
    int IndexOf(T item);
    void Insert(int index, T item);
    void RemoveAt(int index);
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ICollection<T>` is not covariant on the type parameter, whereas `IEnumerable<T>` is. If you look at their declarations ([ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx), [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)) you can see that `IEnumerable<T>` uses the `out` keyword on `T`, while `ICollection<T>` does not.

This makes sense if you think about it, since (roughly speaking) covariance is safe when the interface will only be used to *read* objects (and thus the `out` keyword). `IEnumerable<T>` clearly meets that criterion, whereas `ICollection<T>` is quite the opposite.

As an example of what could go wrong (using your example):

```
IList<String> obj = new List<string>(); // Legal, of course
ICollection<Object> obj1 = obj;         // Illegal, but let's see what happens
obj1.Add(new NonStringObject());        // That's not a string being stored in a List<string>
```

Remember: covariance is not the same as inheritance. Just because two classes or interfaces share an inheritance relation does not mean their type parameters share the same variance characteristics.

Comment: @dlev.Could you please explain it a bit more.what makes `IEnumerable<T>` covariant and `ICollection<T>` does not.

Comment: @Ashely Just updated my answer with that info.

Answer (score 4):

The key here is whether the collection is modifiable.  `IEnumerable<T>` is a *read-only* collection of `T`s, whereas `ICollection<T>` supports `Add`.  A modifiable collection cannot be covariant, because:

```
IList<String> obj = new List<String>();
ICollection<Object> obj1 = obj;
obj1.Add(new Elephant());
```

This would typecheck, since (presumably) `Elephant` is a subclass of `Object`.  But now `obj`, which is a `List<string>` has an `Elephant` as its last element, which is clearly a bad thing.